# Changing color of UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark and UITextField 

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit, ios4

I want to change the color of UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark and UITextField background color where we type. I found this is not straight forward.

Comment: Feel the same way. @Dilshan: go and accept answers to your previous questions, please.

Comment: Just got to know that features. New to stackoverflow :)

Comment: To be clear, there is no obligation to accept answers, but you should accept any that worked for you, both to indicate to future readers the successful solution and to reward the author of that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default,you cannot change the color of **`UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark`**

But alternatively you can use the image for this..as just like **`checkmark`**

while for textField you can use this single line..

```
[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: Specifically, you'd use the `accessoryView` property of the cell instead of `accessoryType`.

Comment: Thanks Ajay But when you call the setBackgroundColor it will set the background color but it will not change the color of the ares where the text resides. I want to change the color of lets say foreground of the text field.

Comment: It is no longer true. Please see the answer by Atanu

Answer (score 47):

I solved this issue by changing the tint color of the `UITableView` where the cell belongs.

Update the Tint Color of `UITableView` in interface builder to Default

or programmatically as below.

For **Objective C**

```
yourTableView.tintColor =  [UIColor blackColor];
```

For **Swift**

```
yourTableView.tintColor = .black
```